# Is there a Node.js function to read the contents of a file on a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

My initial question got marked as a duplicate for a completely unrelated question that has absolutely nothing in common with my question, so I'm reposting this with some clarifications that should hopefully make it clearer what I want to do.

---

Suppose I have a file on a server that is ***NOT*** my server:

```
https://example.com/names.txt
```

Is there a function such that I can read this file as a `String` or as a `Buffer`?

The obvious solution would be to download the file into a temporary directory, read its contents, then delete it, but this is very slow and takes many lines of code. **Is there a cleaner way to do this?**

Comment: I think they're downvoting because the headline makes it seem like a question that has been asked and answered already. Next time, maybe specifying that it's not X might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file is on an http server, you can use one of the http request modules listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) to make a request for that file.  The usual default behavior is to get the response from the http server into memory, though you can put it in a file if you want.

The built-in http library can do this, but it takes more lines of code than the higher level libraries in my link above which is their main benefit.

Here's a simple example using my favorite choice for this type of library the [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) module (which has built-in promise support):

```
const got = require('got');
got("https://someserver.com/somefile.txt").text().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The `got` library has methods `.text()`, `.json()` and `.buffer()` for fetching the response body, parsing it (if necessary) and putting the result into the right type of variable.  My example above uses `.text()` since you mentioned getting the response into a string.  If you want it in a buffer, you would use `.buffer()` instead.

Comment: Over a month later, returning to this specific answer helped a lot, and it's still not clear to me why I didn't mark your answer as correct then. I have now.

Comment: @wibbuffey - Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make a request to that server for that file. (e.g. a GET request) using the module of your choice.

[Making a request with the HTTP module](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs)

Note: in the example, `d` in the `on('data', ...)` callback will be what you want.

Comment: I suppose that's the way to do it. I had hoped there would be a cleaner way, but I guess this is zero-dependency, so...

Comment: Also, from what I can tell in the HTTP docs, it's `.on("response", (data) => {/* ... */)` rather than `.on("data", (data) => {/* ... */})`. (I believe that the `data` event returns when any chunk of data has been returned rather than the whole file, but I am not 100% sure.)

Comment: Yes that is correct, I just put that note there to help a bit.

Comment: @wibbuffey - Yes, `data` in this answer is just one chunk of the file.  It takes more code to accumulate the chunks.  That's why I wrote a different answer about using the `got()` library which accumulates all the data for you and thus is simpler to use.

Comment: @jfriend00 The point of the question was to not include anything (at least, external libraries). For my purpose, using a built-in library (that I am already quite familiar with) would function better than adding another dependency. Thank you regardless, I will have to check out the library for the future